# Cannot extract data from a span itemprop

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I have the following to extract some prices and availabilities from a webpage. But I get Object Required at:

**Set price = ie.Document.querySelector(".price-cont .final-price"**)

Why?

```
Sub getMetaDataInfo()
Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
Dim mylink As String
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Integer
Set wks = wb.Sheets("Info")
Dim i As Integer
lastrow = wks.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow

mylink = wks.Cells([i], 2).Value   

ie.Visible = False
ie.Navigate mylink

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Dim price As Object, availability As Object

Set price = ie.Document.querySelector(".price-cont .price")
wks.Cells(i, "C").Value = price.innerText   

Set availability = ie.Document.querySelector(".inner-box-one .availability")
wks.Cells(i, "D").Value = availability.innerText   

Next i

End Sub
```

I tried to insert the delay like the following

```
Sub getMetaDataInfo()
Dim IE As New InternetExplorer

Dim mylink As String
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Integer
Set wks = wb.Sheets("Info")
Dim i As Integer

lastrow = wks.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

IE.Visible = True


For i = 2 To lastrow

mylink = wks.Cells(i, 2).Value

IE.Visible = False
IE.Navigate mylink


Dim price As Object, t As Date
Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 5

Dim price As Object, availability As Object

While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
t = Timer
Do
    DoEvents
    On Error Resume Next

    Set price = IE.Document.querySelector(".price-cont .final-price")
    wks.Cells(i, "C").Value = price.innerText

    If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
    On Error GoTo 0
Loop
If price Is Nothing Then Exit Sub


Next i

End Sub
```

My scenario is I login first to webpage manually I keep the IE window open I go to excel run macro but..

Comment: Its hard to answer without knowing the source code of webpage, please share the URL

Comment: You also need a proper wait (While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend) and perhaps a timed loop to wait for item to be available. And why are there [] around i?

Comment: It worked just one or two times thats makes me wonder why??! Its a product page which I login first

Comment: You are not allowing enough time. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell without seeing HTML/URL. Have you verified the selector is correct?

Otherwise, the main two things you can do now, in relation to allowing enough time for page to load, are:

1) Add a proper wait before attempting to select

```
While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
```

2) Try a timed loop to allow further load time

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub LoopUntilSet()
    Dim price As Object, t As Date
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 5

    'your other code

    While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
    t = Timer
    Do
        DoEvents
        On Error Resume Next
        Set price = ie.document.querySelector(".price-cont .price")
        If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
        On Error GoTo 0
    Loop
    If price Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    'other code.....
End Sub
```

3) Remove the [] from around `i`

Comment: After I change it I get a strange VBA automation error -2147467259 (800040005)

Comment: On ie.Visible = False but even if change to true the same

Comment: That is not due to my code.Can you [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) you current code with my lines included?

Comment: Seems weird. Try creating an IE object rather than autoinstantiating with Dim ie as New Internet Explorer instead Dim ie As InternetExplorer : Set ie = New InternetExplorer...... also, experiment with InternetExplorerMedium in place of InternetExplorer.

Comment: i did it, with an extra different step. Because it is a login page, I selected visible true with closed IE window. As soon code runs it opens the window I login and then it goes from product to product and it is working..