# VBA javascript button click - Run-time error '424'

Tags: javascript, vba, button, automation, click

first of all let me apologize if it's a stupid question but I'm completely new to coding and been stuck on this pulling my hair out for a couple of days now..

I'm trying to do some automation for my work place, and basically am stuck at trying to make VBA click the js button for me and keep getting 'Run-time error '424': Object required' while trying to do so.

Button code is:

```
<a href="javascript:" id="WIN_0_304316340" arid="304316340" artype="Control" ardbn="z3Btn_ShowApplicationList" artcolor="null" class="btnflt  pointerCursor arfid304316340 ardbnz3Btn_ShowApplicationList" style="top:0px; left:0px; width:23px; height:140px;z-index:1209;" arwindowid="0"><div class="btnimgdiv" style="top:0px; left:0px; width:23px; height:140px;">
```

(or at least that's what I've found by using 'inspect element' option, not 100% sure if this is how I'm supposed to do it considering it's js, as all tutorials I've found so far used simple text forms with pretty clear ID's instead..)

and the VBA code I'm using is:

```
    Sub Test()


    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://CensoredLink.com"

    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop


    IE.document.getElementById("WIN_0_304316340").Click


End Sub
```

As You can see I've tried using the 'WIN_0_304316340' ID in this example, but also tried going with the arid '304316340' as I have no idea which one of these is the correct one (got the same error message in both cases)

when I click debug in the editor it highlights the following line:

```
IE.document.getElementById("WIN_0_304316340").Click
```

so I've also thought that maybe I just did something wrong in here / haven't defined an object or something like that?

My another guess would be that maybe it's somehow relaed to the fact that page loads pretty slowly, for few secs but I guess the

```
  Do While IE.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop
```

part of the code should be preventing that..

Any help would be greatly appreciated and sorry again for being such a noob T__T

Comment: Have you tried inserting a break on the line `IE.document.getElementById("WIN_0_304316340").Click` and waiting for the button to load?

Comment: Not sure what that even means so my guess would be no.. could You please elaborate on how I could do that?

Comment: Sure thing. A break is stopping the code at the line. It can be done either by right clicking on the line and choosing "insert breakpoint" in toggle or pressing the "margin" to the left of the line.

This is to rule out that the page loads too slow compared to your code.

Comment: Further you can step through your code which makes debugging easier. A basic run through of debugging in VBA can be seen here: https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/debugging-vba-code

Comment: try adding a proper wait and a timed loop as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53702384/6241235 You can replace the selector with [arid='304316340'] so change Set price = ie.document.querySelector(".price-cont .price")  ... to .... Set yourVarName = ie.document.querySelector("[arid='304316340']"). If that doesn't work check for a parent iframe/frame tag. Good first post btw +1

Comment: Mr ML, thank you very much for your help, looks like I'm finally getting somewhere with this thanks to You <3

I've inserted the breakpoint as per your instructions and looks like website load time is indeed the problem here - with breakpoint added the code did what it was supposed to and clicked the button without any issues.

Now the only question is... how do I make it work without a breakpoint?

Comment: I've already tried using few different lines of code from different tutorials to force it to wait for the IE to load - sadly to no avail.

I've also tried the line of code sugested by QHar (thank you very much for trying to help too btw I greatly appreciate it)

While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

but this also doesn't help - I'm just getting the same error as before without using a breakpoint.

Are there any other methods I could use to force the code to wait for the page to load?

Comment: In this case there is nothing that a break would achieve that a timed loop wouldn't in my opinion _except_ if the element is present before clickable. You can alter the length of the wait if it needs to be longer by adjusting the constant (note I am referring to my shared link not just the one liner). All the break is doing is adding time. As your error is a not found (not not clickable) I suggest trying to add more wait time to my example. The advantage of the timed loop is no manual intervention plus exit loop on condition.

Comment: Tried fiddling around with your example but couldn't get it to work sadly (guess it might be a bit over my head for now..)
on a bright side I've finally managed to get the script to work with a one liner constant that waits 6 secs before executing the rest of the code  - While not the most elegant solution I can at least finally move on and try to finish the whole script instead of being stuck on first few lines forever.. So thank you very much for your help guys, you've been absolutely great <3